# How do I prove this limit does not exist: $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac1x\sin\left(\frac1x\right)$

Tags: calculus, limits

How do I prove this limit does not exist:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{x}\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$

In book they have done using Cauchy criteria for finite limits, which I don't seem to understand, so I am looking for alternate way. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}1/x\sin(1/x)=\lim_{y\rightarrow \infty}y\sin(y)$$

It suffices to show the above limit doesn't exists.

Consider $y_n=\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi n\to \infty$,

Also consider $z_n=\pi+2\pi n\to \infty$

But the function on these two sequences have different limits, so the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: .Thanks for the answer .Sorry i did not understand sequential definition of continuity . But without it , i can see that as y goes to infinity sin(1/y) just oscillates bw 1 and -1 ,but y goes to infinity , so product goes to infinity and hence limit doesnot exist .Pls correct me .Thanks

Comment: your idea is correct. But "product goes to infinity" is wrong, the product keeps oscillating between $-\infty$ and -$\infty$, so the limit doesn't exists. You can say there exist a few points $(y_n)$ which goes to $\infty$ and product on such $y_n$ goes to $\infty$